# How to encourage our 11 month old to walk alone?

Tags: infant, walking

Since about 3 month, our little one can walk and stand, when both her hands are being held or she can hold onto something. As soon as we retract our hands and she realizes it, she will sit down.

Since about 1.5 months now, she decided that she can nicely hop on her knees. So when she needs to use her hands, she does not crawl but "walk" or hop on her knees. She also does that if she is in an especially good mood.

No "accidents" happened to her while walking with help and also learning to stand by herself went without anything more than the usual(?) minor drops. In general shes a brave one and likes to explore new things and areas - in those cases even crawling/rushing away from the parents. But shes very clingy in areas she already knows (e.g. she plays by herself on the floor sitting next to me, if i get up and sit onto the couch she will shortly after stand next to me). She still sleeps with us in the room and usually after waking up after 8h sleep around 4 o'clock in the morning is allowed to sleep another 2-3h with us in the big bed.

Did we -somehow- fail in giving her enough self-confidence? Failed to give her the proper incentive? Maybe shes just lazy and we skip her and try our luck with a new one (*joking*)? What might be our mistake?

Do you have any advises for us how we can get her to walk all by herself?

Comment: Oh my gosh no. You did not fail at all. All children are different and learn at different paces. The only thing a child **requires** is love. Do that, and your child will be fine.

Comment: Just from my experience, my boy started walking at 9 months, how did this happen he started moving with thing's, what I did I do to improve self confidence. .. I cheered him up eg ( I'd say go baby go baby, you can do it) unbelievably this worked by 1yr he was fully walking and running everywhere with full confidence. I never taught him how to walk bUT i cheered him up. He managed to do it on his own. I learned that dont rush them, they always learn.That said kids are different but do try cheering and clapping.

Comment: 11 months is still fairly early for walking. What you describe is perfectly normal http://www.babycenter.com/0_your-childs-walking-timeline_10357004.bc

Answer (score 3):

Walking is not something that needs you to 'push', unless your child is substantially behind (and 11 months is ahead, not behind).  Looking at the [Denver Developmental Screening chart](http://www.umsl.edu/~garziar/Media%20folder/denverform_front.jpeg), the 50th percentile is around 12 months, and many children take until 13 to 15 months to walk.

In my opinion, you're better off continuing as you have: give your child the opportunity to walk when she wants to, and she will learn how in her own time.  Learning how to learn things is an important skill as well as the skill she's learning itself, after all - so the more you can let her figure things out for herself at her own pace, the better off she will be.